# Confusion over IORefs to make a counter

Tags: haskell, monads, ioref, unsafe-perform-io

I found some sample code, and changed it a little

```
counter = unsafePerform $ newIORef 0

newNode _ = unsafePerformIO $
              do
                i <- readIORef counter
                writeIORef counter (i+1)
                return i
```

Which returns 1 then 2 then 3 then 3 etc each time it's run.

But when I change it to

```
newNode = unsafePerformIO $
              do
                i <- readIORef counter
                writeIORef counter (i+1)
                return i
```

then I get 0 every time I run it.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your second version `newNode` is a simple value, not a function. So haskell evaluates it exactly once and then gives you the result of that evaluation whenever you access `newNode`.

A word of warning: Using `unsafePerformIO` on anything other than an IO action which you know to be referentially transparent is dangerous. It might interact badly with some optimizations and just generally not behave like you expect. There's a reason it's got the word "unsafe" in its name.

As a way to play around with `unsafePerformIO` your code is fine, but if you ever want to use something like it in real code, I'd strongly encourage you to reconsider.

Comment: Why is it not treated a nonary function?

Comment: @MrBones: Because that behavior would almost never be what people want. If I write `x = veryExpensiveFunction foobar` and then later `y = x * x + x`, I want `veryExpensiveFunction foobar` to be evaluated once, not thrice. And that's exactly what Haskell does (unless `x`'s type is polymorphic). The only reason you want it to behave like a nullary function in this case is that evaluating the expression has side-effects, which isn't something that can even happen without unsafe operations.

Comment: There is no such thing as a nonary function in haskell. Functions all take one value (which may be a tuple) and return one value (which may be another function). Functions are not "invoked" -- they are applied to values, to yield values. Do you seriously want `foo = 1 + 2` to be the function which tells the processor to add 1 and two every time you use the word foo!?

Comment: Aha. I forgot about functions all being of a -> b, so I guess nonary can't possibly work with that, and what appears nonary isn't. Cheers

Comment: Independently of whether a value can be considered a 0-argument function (which, IMO, loosely it can - just like 'x -> y -> z' can be thought of loosely as the type of binary functions), purity means that such a function must always return the same value.  It is always called with the same set of arguments (none), and therefore must always return the same value or it is by definition not pure and to use 'unsafePerformIO' to assert that it is would be incorrect.

Comment: Currently (GHC 7.6.3) `newNode ()` is sure to interact badly with optimizations: when compiled with `-O` it only runs once! E.g., `newNode () + newNode ()` evaluates to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Just as a clarification: for an application like the one you seem to be building, *creating* an IORef using `unsafePerformIO` is quite normal, and allows Haskell's closest approximation to global variables in procedural languages. What is probably not wise is using it in your actions. For example, newNode is probably best written as:

```
newNode = do i <- readIORef counter
             writeIORef counter (i+1)
             return i
```

And then any place you intend to call `newNode` should be an IO action itself.

One other little detail: `counter` will have the type `IORef Integer` by default unless you change this using `default`. Don't try to give it a generic type like `Num a => IORef a`: that way danger lies.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the dangers you speak of with using `Num a => IORef a`?

Comment: Because the typesystem gets screwed upo with it. I read somewhere about this, but can't find the ressource anymore. Probably in the sourcecode for `unsafePerformIO`

Comment: @Grazer: It can violate type safety; see [the documentation for `unsafePerformIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO).  (Although their example now prints `"*"` for me, instead of dumping core, that still shouldn't be possible.)  You can also produce a value which changes the second time you evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

Yous shouldn't use such constructs in a normal programming, as the compiler may apply various optimizations that kill the desired effect or make it unpredictable. If possible, use something like the `State` monad instead. It's cleaner and will always behave like you want. Here you go:

```
-- This function lets you escape from the monad, it wraps the computation into a monad to make it, well, countable
counter :: (State Int x) -> x
counter = flip evalState 0

-- Increments the counter and returns the new counter
newNode :: State Int Int
newNode = modify (+1) >>= get
```

Please see what sepp2k sad for the answer to your question. What you explain is particularly useful, if you have something global available (like configs), unlikely to change, which must be available from nearly everywhere. Use it wisely, as it is against the basic principle of purity. If it's possible, use monads instead (like I explained).

Comment: To underline the answers here -- the best way to fix it is to not ever ever ever ever *ever* **ever** use `unsafePerformIO` unless you *really* really *really* **really** r-r-r-e-e-e-a-a-a-l-l-l-y know what you're doing and why you need it. And even then, probably don't use it.