# Global variables via unsafePerformIO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

The GHC API requires that some initialisation occurs before invocation.  Specifically, `parseStaticFlags` can only be called once.

I have functions that can call `runGhc :: MaybeFilePath :: Ghc a -> IO a` multiple times to run some GHC API methods.  However, some of that initialisation should only occur the first time that function is called.

I seem to remember from `Yi` source that it is possible to create a global variable something like

```
ghcInitialised :: MVar (Bool,[String])
ghcInitialised = unsafePerformIO $ newMVar (False,[])
```

so that in the monadic action that calls `runGhc` we can have

```
(init,flags) <- readMVar ghcInitialised
when (not init) $ do
   ...
   (_,_,staticFlagWarnings) <- parseStaticFlags ...
   ...
   putMVar ghcInitialised (True,staticFlagWarnings)
```

However, I can not recall exactly how it is done.  This code is in the `runMonad` function for the monad that wraps a `GhcMonad`.  I am well aware that using `unsafePerformIO` is not pure or functional, but (at the time) this was the best way of achieving a practical result.

[Edit: the working solution:

```
{-# NOINLINE ghcInitialised #-}
ghcInitialised :: MVar (Bool,[String])
ghcInitialised = unsafePerformIO $ newMVar (False,[])
```

so that in the monadic action that calls `runGhc` we can have

```
(init,flags) <- takeMVar ghcInitialised
when (not init) $ do
   ...
   (_,_,staticFlagWarnings) <- parseStaticFlags ...
   ...
   putMVar ghcInitialised (True,staticFlagWarnings)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461684/confusion-over-iorefs-to-make-a-counter/4465987#4465987). It shows how to use a global counter that 'ticks' everytime you look at it. You don't need a counter, but instead of `+1`, you just put `True` into it.

Or, even better, you put the initialisation code into the `unsafePerformIO`, (guarded by an `if` of course).

Comment: Ah, I should have used `IORef` not `MVar`.

Comment: No, MVar is good.  MVar is in fact better, since it works even with concurrency.

Comment: My program was hanging when I used `MVar`s.

Comment: Your `readMVar` should be a `takeMVar`, otherwise `putMVar` will block.

Comment: But beware, if you switch to a `takeMVar` you'll need a `putMVar` to match it even when it's already initialized.

Comment: Thanks @ShiDoiShi and @augustss, my code works with `takeMVar` and `putMVar` (as well as with IORefs).

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn inlining off.
The other important thing: The type has to be monomorph (= no type variables), otherwise you might evaluate unsafePerformIO for each actual type.

```
{-# NOINLINE ghcInitialised #-}
ghcInitialised :: MVar (Bool,[String])
ghcInitialised = unsafePerformIO $ newMVar (False,[])
```